# Using a value from a matrix as a multiplier in an equation?

Tags: matlab

Started using MatLab a couple of weeks ago, I don't know much proper syntax / terminology.

I'm trying to use a value in a `3x1` matrix as a multiplier in an equation later.

This is to draw a circle with radius and centre point defined by values input by the user.

I have a pop-up window, the values are input by the user and stored in this `3x1 cell` (labelled `answer`).

How do I use the second value of that matrix, `answer(2)`, in the following equation:

x = 'answer(2)' * cos(theta) + xCentre;

This error message appears:

```
Error using  .* 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in Disks (line 40)
x = 'answer(2)'.* cos(theta) + xCentre;
```

Comment: could it be that you have a string `'answer(2)'` instead of just `answer(2)`?

Comment: If `answer` is a cell, then you will also need to use `answer{2}` (note curly brackets) otherwise you will get errors about `mtimes not defined for a cell`.

Answer (score 0):

In `MATLAB`, apostrophes (`''`) define a string. If the name of your matrix is `answer`, you can refer to its second value by the command `answer(2)` as mentioned by @Schorsch. For more infos on vectors and matrices, you can check [this site](http://www.math.utah.edu/~eyre/computing/matlab-intro/matrices.html).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the previous answer says, its important to understand what exactly you are doing before you do it. Only add the ('') if you are defining a string, which generally occurs when dealing with variables. In your case, you simply have a matrix, which is not a string, but rather a set of numbers. You can simply do answer(2) as aforementioned, because answer(2) calls up the second value in your matrix while 'answer(2)' has you trying to define some variable that does not exist.

the most important thing is truly understanding what you are doing to avoid the basic syntax errors.